# How to make will_paginate work with liquid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, liquid

I managed to make a little hack to make will_paginate work with liquid:
http://gist.github.com/426737

I wonder if this is safe? Ideas?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to know about this.

Comment: maybe you would have more luck with kaminari and `rails g kaminari:views` and swapping erb out for liquid?

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be safer if you tried something like this: https://gist.github.com/2783697

Basically, that defines a Liquid Block that uses WillPaginate to paginate your collection.