# liquid pagination in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, liquid

Im using will_paginate outside of liquid and it works fine. Now I try to paginate a collection in  a liquid view. I found this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981124/how-to-make-will-paginate-work-with-liquid) which lead me to this [source](https://gist.github.com/etagwerker/2783697)

The collection is created in my controller like this:

```
collection_assign = object.items.collect {|x| x.to_drop}
```

the to_drop method throws every item to the drop table:

```
  def to_drop
    Drops::ItemDrop.new self
  end
```

I attach the assigns to the template and render them with the template. Without the paginate tag everything is working, so the data is passed to the liquid view and for tags are working. The "paginate" tag is also registered and responding. But working with paginate like this:

```
{% paginate items by 5 %}
{% for item in items %}
<p>{{ item.title }}</p>
{% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

throws an error:

```
Liquid::SyntaxError (Liquid syntax error: Syntax Error in 'paginate' - Valid syntax: paginate <collection> by <number>)
```

I think this error concerns the collection, which is obviously an array. What kind of collection type is liquid expecting and how can I pass it to the liquid template?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has the same troubles, maybe this solution also works for you:

I figured out that will_paginate is still working, when i pass an paginated object to liquid but it only showed the first "slice". This was a very important step to the solution because now I just needed to pass the specific controller to allow liquid the urls for will_paginate to be accessable. By doing so, the pagination links were accessable manually by typing them in the browsers adress bar (e.g. "?page=2").

After that I created a new column in the specific database. This column contains a calculated value for the necessary pages. The value for the number of pages is calculated in a helper class by using division and modulo operators. The helper class has to be implemented in all controller actions that can have an impact on the number of pages so that the value in the database can be updated.

After getting the value for the number of necessary pages it can also be passed to liquid as an object attribute. Now its possible to generate the links manually from scratch in a for loop in liquid .

Quite a hacky way and maybe not the smoothest way to achieve that, I guess, but the most important thing is, it works!